# Functions & Relations on Sets of Real Numbers.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Functions & Relations on finite Sets:

a) The circle relation $C$ was defined as follows:

- For any $(x,y) \in \mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, $(x,y) \in C$ means that $x^2+y^2=4$.
- Is $C$ a function? If it is, find $C(0)$ and $C(2)$.

b) Defined a relation from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ as follows:

- For all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, $(x,y) \in M$ means that $x^2-y=0$.
- Is $M$ a function? If it is, find $M(-1)$ and $M(0)$.

pls. Help me my assignment?

Comment: What is the def of *function* in the context of set theory ? Relation $C \subseteq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is a function iff for every $x$ in the domain there is only one $y$ such that $(x,y) \in C$.

Comment: Rephrased... is $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$ a function?  If so, what is $f(0)$, what is $f(2)$?  Is $g(x)=x^2$ a function?  If so, what is $g(-1)$, what is $g(0)$?  Do you see why this rephrasing is effectively your original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

A function is a set of ordered pairs such that for every $x$ there is **at most one** $y$ such that pair $(x,y)$ is an element of the function.

If for a fixed $x$ such $y$ indeed exists (in words: $x$ is an element of the domain of the function) then $$y:=f(x)$$